# UTL_HTTP throwing 400 bad response error

Tags: oracle

I'm running this code on my Oracle instance. But it is giving me error: 400 (BAD REQUEST)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url  varchar2(4000) := 'http://ec2-52-203-125-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test.php';
begin
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'GET','HTTP/1.1');
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response status code: ' || res.status_code);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response status code: ' || res.reason_phrase);

  exception
    when others then
      utl_http.end_response(res);  
end;
/
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have a leading space in ' HTTP/1.1' Remove that.

Comment: Did you try that HTTP request outside PL/SQL, e.g. using `curl`? What was the result?